# Android Espresso: Testing error message is shown?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I have a test that is supposed to test the visibility of an error msg when there is no network connection, but I dunno how to get it to show?

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class PostsActivityTest {

@Rule
public final ActivityRule<PostsActivity> rule = new ActivityRule<>(PostsActivity.class);

PostsActivity postsActivity;

@Before
public void init() {
    postsActivity = rule.get();
}

@Test
public void testShouldShowErrorViewOnNetworkError() {
    postsActivity.showErrorMsg(); // doesn't work
    onView(withId(R.id.error_view)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

When calling `postsActivity.showErrorMsg();` I get a crash stating `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

This is the `showErrorMsg()` in `PostsActivity`:

```
public void showErrorMsg() {
    errorView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Using `runOnUiThread` seems to be working. I dunno if this is the preferred way though.

```
@Test
public void testShouldShowErrorViewOnNetworkError() {
    postsActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            postsActivity.showErrorMsg();
        }
    });
    onView(withId(R.id.error_view)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `Espresso` tests you should not directly call methods of your `Activity`. You should use `Espresso` to interact with the UI like a real user.

#### Why `runOnUiThread` is required:

When running instrumentation tests (e.g. `Espresso` tests) there are actually two apps involved. First the app that is being tested and the app that executes the tests. Both use different main threads.

If you call `PostsActivity#showErrorMsg` from your test, it is running in the testing apps thread. But manipulating views in Android is only allowed from the apps UI Thread. If you really have to call `PostsActivity#showErrorMsg` from your test, `runOnUiThread` is the right choice.

#### How to improve

So instead of calling `PostsActivity#showErrorMsg` directly from your test, use `Espresso` to `click()` e.g. on a `Button` that will call that method for you:

```
@Test
public void testShouldShowErrorViewOnNetworkError() {
    onView(withId(R.id.post_button)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.error_view)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

Comment: Yea, I wanted to do the perform click line of code, but how would I trigger a network error on a button click to show the error message? That's why I kinda resorted to just calling the Activity directly.

Comment: You shouldn't use real network in your tests. Your tests depend on the availability of a network resource. Testing the ui is much more stable and easier when dependencies (especially external resources) are mocked or stubbed. Replace the network layer with a mock/stub when testing.